# Use miltiple input type=text with checkbox

Tags: php, html, checkbox, foreach

Hello i want to use multiple input type text and same checkboxes along with them to access values by post request in php but problem is if i check the checkbox it will show one item respected to checkbox but it shows all elements of input type text from **foreach**

I have used :

```
<input type="text" name="nam[]" value="xyz">

<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="xyz1">
```

Same with10 inputs.

It's work with `inputs`, but how can i acheive the same with `checkboxs`?

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: How to get single input type text related to checkbox item from foreach

Answer (score 0):

### Hope this code will help you:

### form.php page:

```
<form method="POST" action="process.php">
<table>
<?php
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    echo '<tr><td><input type="text" name="nam['.$i.']" value="input'.($i+1).'"></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="chk['.$i.']" value="checkbox'.($i+1).'"></td></tr>';
}
?>
<tr><td><input type="submit"></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

### process.php

```
<?php
foreach($_POST['chk'] as $key=>$value){
    echo 'Checkbox value = '.$value.' and input value = '.$_POST['nam'][$key].'<hr />';
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry sir but it start input text from array [0]

Comment: so what, what ever your check box is checked, you found the same key value from input box. For your confusion please use `print_r($_POST);` to see the result in `process.php`

Comment: In my program if i check 7th value then it get checkbox 7 but get input text value start from array[0]

Comment: see my process.php page carefully. where foreach give you the number checked key.so if you check checkbox7 then it will give you key 6 so you cant use `$_POST['nam'][6]`; to see the input value. hope u got it

Comment: Sorry sir i have not set the key value

Comment: In your situation you have to use key for 10 input and checkbox. run my form.php file in your browser and see the inspect element or view page source carefully.Hope you will got the tricks. thanks.